# Implementing delay() without time()

Tags: c, time, delay

I'm writing code for an embedded device (no OS so no system calls or anything) and I need to have a delay but the compiler doesn't supply `time.h`. What other options do I have?

Comment: Many embedded devices include a timer or clock hardware device that can be programmed to send an interrupt after a time period.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Can you use `select`? It has a timeout parameter.

Comment: @ugoren `select` is a system call :(

Comment: @chux the C51 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the clock of your system you may implement delays using the NOP (no operation) assembler instruction. You may calculate the time of one NOP depending on the MIPS of your system, so for example if 1 `NOP` is `1[us]`, then you could implement something like:

```
void delay(int ms)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ms*1000; i++)
    {
        asm(NOP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the device.  Can you enable a stable timer interrupt?  You might only be able to busy-wait and wait for a timer interrupt.  How accurate this is likely to be (and how accurate it needs to be) is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For short fixed time delays, a do-nothing loop will meet the need, but of course, will need calibration.

```
void Delay_ms(unsigned d /* ms */) {
  while (d-- > 0) {
    unsigned i;
    i = 2800;  // Calibrate this value
    // Recommend that the flowing while loop's asm code is check for tightness.
    while (--i);
    /* add multiple _nop_() here should you want precise calibration */
  }
}
```